# Is there the expression about toilet talk?

Tags: phrase-usage

About toilet talk in English, is there the expression like the following?

> Would you like to go upstairs?

Comment: Could you explain what the expression means?

Comment: @Tim S, it means "Do you want to go to latrine?, I think.

Comment: "upstairs" is not a euphemism for the latrine in AmE.

Comment: In AmE, if anything that would be a sexual proposition. http://www.menshealth.com/sex-women/convince-her-to-go-upstairs-with-you

Comment: @ Stephen S,the expression in my OP is BrE.

Comment: Dropping the Browns off at the Superbowl.

Answer (score 1):

[This wikipedia link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_toilet_slang) contains English slang similar to the above, many of which I have never heard. The closest appears to be

> Going to the little girls'/little boys' room

which is AmE, or

> Going to the office

although I don't believe I have ever heard this. If you mean an expression that states using the bathroom, not "going to _______," but politely, try

> Answer nature's call
>
> Going number one (or number two for solid stuff)
>
> Relieve oneself
>
> Taking a leak
>
> Dropping a load

Comment: The last several look fine to use. I would NOT suggest using ***going to the office*** or ***going to the little boys/girls room***.

Comment: "Dropping a load" is hardly polite. "Going to the men's [or ladies'] room" would be typical for a business situation.